# Texthero TD-IDF Calculation

Tags: python, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

What is the difference in calculating TF-IDF through Texthero:

```
import texthero as hero
s = pd.Series(["Sentence one", "Sentence two"])
hero.tfidf(s, return_feature_names=True)
0    [0.5797386715376657, 0.8148024746671689, 0.0]
1    [0.5797386715376657, 0.0, 0.8148024746671689]
['Sentence', 'one', 'two'])
```

and the TD-IDF from sklearn? I would expect the results from sklearn given these example sentences.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
...
Sentence    one two
0   0.0 0.346574    0.000000
1   0.0 0.000000    0.346574
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**

`tfidf` does not preprocess the input text and just apply the TF-IDF algorithm, whereas by default `TfidfVectorizer` preprocess the input.

**Functions signature**

The difference lays in the way you are supposed to deal with the two frameworks.

Look at the functions signatures:

scikit-learn `TfidfVectorizer`:

```
sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer(
    *, 
    input='content', 
    encoding='utf-8', 
    decode_error='strict', 
    strip_accents=None, 
    lowercase=True, 
    preprocessor=None, 
    tokenizer=None, 
    analyzer='word', 
    stop_words=None, 
    token_pattern='(?u)\b\w\w+\b', 
    ngram_range=(1, 1), 
    max_df=1.0, 
    min_df=1, 
    max_features=None, 
    vocabulary=None, 
    binary=False, 
    dtype=<class 'numpy.float64'>, 
    norm='l2', 
    use_idf=True, 
    smooth_idf=True, 
    sublinear_tf=False
)
```

Texthero `tfidf`:

```
tfidf(
    s: pandas.core.series.Series, 
    max_features=None, 
    min_df=1, 
    return_feature_names=False
)
```

In case of scikit-learn, the different text preprocessing steps are included in the `TfidfVectorizer`. In the case of the `tfidf` of Texthero, there is no text preprocessing.

**Your example**

In your example, tf-idf values are different in the two cases as for instance `TfidfVectorizer` by default convert all characters to lowercase.

**Which one is better?**

Depending on your task, one of the two solution might be more convenient.

If you are working with Pandas Dataframe/Series on a natural language preprocessing task and you want to have a fine-control over your code, then it's probably convenient to use `tfidf`.

If, on the other hand, you are working on a more generic ML task where you also need to deal with some text and just want to quickly represent it, then you might opt for `TfidfVectorizer` using the default settings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I don't get is how hero.tfidf can get to the results displayed, following the TF-IDF algorithm.

Comment: Can you please share all the code you used (also for the `TfidfVectorizer ` part)? I will try to compare the two by adding a new section in the answer.

Comment: It turned out the difference was indeed caused by the parameter settings used.